# Missing second reviewer stats on edit suggestion info page

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

The info page for a given edit suggestion shows the people who approved it, and "stats" about them, but the stats list only shows the first reviewer, not the second. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/232936):

[image: Screenshot of the suggestion page]

Comment: I wonder if the view is any different for a mod. We do get more data, but only Stack Overflow has multiple reviewers currently.

Comment: @Michael, I have noticed this too.  Not sure why I didn't choose to report it.  Thanks.

Comment: @jjnguy I didn't even realize the info page said who'd voted until now; I'm pretty happy about it

Comment: @Michael, yeah.  I like seeing the stats too.

Comment: @Michael ~ Sorta like "consecutive edits don't update correctly for the summary page" bug?

Comment: @GraceNote will do, didn't know if you would get pinged on new chat messages in the Tavern as it didn't auto pop your name. I'll just link you now to the pertinent start of the transcript, won't take you but a moment to find. start: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/507613#507613 end: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/507640#507640

Comment: Uf, a bit much there, @drachenstern. If you can wait 4+ hours I can assist you then.

Comment: @GraceNote I can wait for days or weeks, I was just curious. It's also why I came and tracked you down ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed, we now display stats of all voters in the page.